# Changing the figsize in the upsetplot module

Tags: python, figure, figsize, upsetplot

How I can change the figsize in the [`upsetplot`](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module in Python? I see that there is a `fig` parameter, but I don't get how to assign a new figure with a predefined size to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matplotlib to define a figure, and then pass it to upsetplot. However, the figure size is reset automatically by upsetplot unless `element_size=None` is set.

So please use something like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from upsetplot import generate_counts, plot

example = generate_counts()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
plot(example, fig=fig, element_size=None)
plt.show()
```

Thanks for inspiring the development of an example on this topic: [Customising element size and figure size](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_sizing.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joel, it definitely helps!